# Need a routine to detect strings that are similar but not identical

Tags: string, delphi

I have a list of strings, some of which have been modified since my previous release.  Some of the changes are trivial (spacing, off by one word, etc).  I would like to detect strings that have only "minor" differences, so that I can try to use the older translations if at all possible.

What do I mean by "minor differences"? I will not know until I start working with the database.

DO you know of any tunable routines that will indicate when two strings are similar but not identical?  Any routines that will return a number indicating how different two strings are?

Comment: You're going to need a way to grade how similar strings are. There are a million ways to do it. Here's a thread, see the various answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323977/string-similarity-score-hash

Comment: It sure would be cool if you found something new that wasn't in the links above or below. Please come back and tell us what you did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many such algorithms. Keywords are **fuzzy string matching**.

A well known one is a [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). By it you can calculate the number of "changes" required to transform one string into another, so that gives you an estimate of how similar the strings are.

See also this question: [How to search for similar words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886835/how-to-search-for-similar-words) for solutions in Delphi.

Comment: See also [how-do-you-implement-levenshtein-distance-in-delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/q/54797/576719).